# Setting username password for Milvus ATTU server

Tags: docker, authentication, milvus

I have used docker-compose to install milvus, attu on ec2 machine.
Below is my docker-compose file.

```html
version: '3.5'
services:
  etcd:
    container_name: milvus-etcd
    image: quay.io/coreos/etcd:v3.5.5
    environment:
      - ETCD_AUTO_COMPACTION_MODE=revision
      - ETCD_AUTO_COMPACTION_RETENTION=1000
      - ETCD_QUOTA_BACKEND_BYTES=4294967296
      - ETCD_SNAPSHOT_COUNT=50000
    volumes:
      - ${DOCKER_VOLUME_DIRECTORY:-.}/volumes/etcd:/etcd
    command: etcd -advertise-client-urls=http://127.0.0.1:2379 -listen-client-urls http://0.0.0.0:2379 --data-dir /etcd
  attu:
    container_name: attu
    image: zilliz/attu:v2.2.3
    environment:
      MILVUS_URL: milvus-standalone:19530
      common.security.authorizationEnabled: "true"
      # ATTU_ENABLE_AUTH: "true"
      # ATTU_USERNAME: rohan  
      # ATTU_PASSWORD: Viscaria@2567
    ports:
      - "8001:3000"
    depends_on:
      - "standalone"
  minio:
    container_name: milvus-minio
    image: minio/minio:RELEASE.2022-03-17T06-34-49Z
    environment:
      MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: minioadmin
      MINIO_SECRET_KEY: minioadmin
    volumes:
      - ${DOCKER_VOLUME_DIRECTORY:-.}/volumes/minio:/minio_data
    command: minio server /minio_data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:9000/minio/health/live"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 3
  # nginx-auth:
  #   container_name: nginx-auth
  #   image: nginx:latest
  #   volumes:
  #     - ./etc/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
  #   ports:
  #     - "82:80"
  #   depends_on:
  #     - attu
  standalone:
    container_name: milvus-standalone
    image: milvusdb/milvus:v2.2.8
    command: ["milvus", "run", "standalone"]
    environment:
      ETCD_ENDPOINTS: etcd:2379
      MINIO_ADDRESS: minio:9000
    volumes:
      - ${DOCKER_VOLUME_DIRECTORY:-.}/volumes/milvus:/var/lib/milvus
    ports:
      - "19530:19530"
      - "9091:9091"
    depends_on:
      - "etcd"
      - "minio"

networks:
  milvus:
```

I want to setup username and password for the attu server, so that only users i want can access to the database, because currently if we click on connect, it connects without any authentication.

Below is the screenshot of Attu UI that comes up.

[image]

Comment: How is this question related to programming?